# ValueError with a List in an Algorithms Problem (Python 3)

Tags: python, list, algorithm, sorting, valueerror

I am working on an algorithms problem at https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/, and I my code is

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums : [int], target: int) -> [int]:
        unsorted = nums[:]
        nums.sort()

        first = 0
        second = len(nums) - 1

        while nums[first] + nums[second] != target:
            if nums[first] + nums[second] < target:
                first += 1
            elif nums[first] + nums[second] > target:
                second -= 1

        return [unsorted.index(nums[first]), unsorted.index(nums[second], first+1)]
```

But, for some reason, whenever I input the test input of [5, 75, 25], 100, I get the error of `return [unsorted.index(nums[first]), unsorted.index(nums[second], first+1)] ValueError: 75 is not in list`. Does anyone know why I it is saying that 75 is not in my unsorted list, and what I could do to fix this? I have tried various other test cases, and this is the only one that is causing problems for me. Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Create a tuple with the first element as an index and the second element as value.

Sort the tuple based on values, Then apply the basic two-pointer algorithm to solve this two sum problem.

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums : [int], target: int) -> [int]:
        
        tp = []
        for index,value in enumerate(nums):
            tp.append((index,value))
        tp.sort(key = lambda x : (x[1]))

        first = 0
        second = len(tp) - 1

        while first<second:
            if tp[first][1] + tp[second][1] == target:
                return [tp[first][0],tp[second][0]]
            elif tp[first][1] + tp[second][1] < target:
                first += 1
            elif tp[first][1] + tp[second][1] > target:
                second -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue come from the `unsorted.index(nums[second], first+1)` part, because the first+1 index is valid on the sorted list but not on the unsorted list. The first+1 is useless and you can just search throughout the whole unsorted list like this:

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums : [int], target: int) -> [int]:
        unsorted = nums[:]
        nums.sort()

        first = 0
        second = len(nums) - 1

        while nums[first] + nums[second] != target:
            if nums[first] + nums[second] < target:
                first += 1
            elif nums[first] + nums[second] > target:
                second -= 1

        return [unsorted.index(nums[first]), unsorted.index(nums[second])] # remove the first+1 startpoint here.
```

and the output for your input is `[2, 1]`

Answer (score 0):

I have used this logic **n=target-nums**, you can use a dictionary to store the indexes of the values. I have also pasted my code for reference, hope this might help you.

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        h={}
        for i, num in enumerate(nums):
            n = target - num
            if n not in h:
                h[num]=i
            else:
                return [h[n], i]
```